# Trying To Connect to Native Mongo DB Driver

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connnect to Mongo DB Driver and I am getting this error:[image: Click Here to View Screen Shot of Error:]

This is code I copy and pasted from the starter documents on the website. I changed the hostname to my first and last name and the uri connection to my server:

[image: Click Here to view Screen Shot of Code]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, provide code and error as formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Do you try to connect to Atlas instance or to your local instance?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue, while trying to create a demo app, I updated my password using autogenerate password, i.e I clicked on auto generate password and pasted it in connection string, it worked for me.

[image: MongoDB]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mongodb+srv://` you should be using `mongodb://`

#### DNS SeedList Format

`mongodb+srv` requires additional settings on DNS which contains seedlist, commonly use for sharded clusters and replica set

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#std-label-connections-dns-seedlist

#### Standard Connection String Format

If you are connecting to a standalone you should be using the standard connection string format.

`mongodb://<username>:<password>:<IP/Hostname>:<Port>/<database>`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format

#### Creating User with Password

To create a username with password you should be using `db.createUser()` which can be found here.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/

Example ( To create a Admin user )

```
use admin;
db.createUser({ 
    username: 'brianlevin', 
    pwd: passwordPrompt(),
    roles: [ { role: 'admin', db: 'databasename' }]
 })
```